# What is the difference between vm.$set and Vue.set?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have carefully read and re-read the Vue docs ["Reactivity in Depth"](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) and the API for [vm.$set](http://vuejs.org/api/#vm-set) and [Vue.set](http://vuejs.org/api/#Vue-set) but I am still having a difficult time determining when to use which.  It is important for me to be able to distinguish between the two because in my current Laravel project, we are setting a lot of properties on objects dynamically.

The distinction in the docs seems to be between the language that vm.$set is "For Vue instance" while Vue.set is "For plain data objects" and that Vue.set is global:

> However, there are ways to add a property and make it reactive after
> an instance has been created.
>
> For Vue instances, you can use the $set(path, value) instance method:

```
vm.$set('b', 2)
// `vm.b` and `data.b` are now reactive
```

> For plain data objects, you can use the global Vue.set(object, key,
> value) method:

```
Vue.set(data, 'c', 3)
// `vm.c` and `data.c` are now reactive
```

Finally, I was wondering if the 3rd "option" of doing the above (which is for adding multiple properties at one time) could be used as an equivalent substitute for either of the 2 options above (by adding just 1 property instead of multiple)?

> Sometimes you may want to assign a number of properties on to an
> existing object, for example using Object.assign() or _.extend().
> However, new properties added to the object will not trigger changes.
> In such cases, create a fresh object with properties from both the
> original object and the mixin object:

```
// instead of `Object.assign(this.someObject, { a: 1, b: 2 })`
this.someObject = Object.assign({}, this.someObject, { a: 1, b: 2 })
```

Comment: I dont get your question. You say it, vm.$set is for instances and Vue.set is to glablly define reactive data.

Comment: If you can explain the difference between the two and how the 3rd option fits in, then you'd have the answer to my question

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Here is the release note that went with the introduction of Vue.set:

> Vue no longer extends Object.prototype with $set and $delete methods.
>   This has been causing issues with libraries that rely on these
>   properties in certain condition checks (e.g. minimongo in Meteor).
>   Instead of object.$set(key, value) and object.$delete(key), use the
>   new global methods Vue.set(object, key, value) and Vue.delete(object,
>   key).

So, `.$set` used to be available on *all* objects - it is now only available on a View Model itself. `Vue.set` is therefore used in those cases now when you have a reference to a reactive object but do not have a reference to the View Model it belongs to.

Comment: Thank you, David.  Would it be better to always use Vue.set then?  How does the 3rd option fit in to this, besides the fact that it can set more than 1 key/value?

Comment: I think the third option is really a performance trade off. `Vue.set` and `vm.$set` are going to be pretty targeted operations while the new object assignment approach will be more costly. If you are adding one attribute to an existing object with many attributes, use one of the set calls. If you are adding many attributes to an object with few existing attributes, use the assignment approach.

Answer (score 13):

In simpler terms, Both are same, `$set` available inside component(instance) like `this.$set()`, where as `Vue.set` is static method available globally.

```
this.$set(someobject, 'key', 'value')

Vue.set(someobject, 'key', 'value')
```

Answer (score 0):

found that add more than one attribute to an object with `.$set()` only once works well, maybe Vue firstly collected these added attributes to a sequence and then apply these sequence to the getter and setter; e.g.

```
Vue.set(this.b,'first','first');
this.b.second = 'second';
this.b.third = 'third';
this.b.fourth = 'fourth';
```

`'second','third','fourth'` are alse reactive as `'first'`