# Vue.js .$set is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to modify the data that stored in vuejs by using `$set` function. But I got this error: `TypeError: app.messageBox.$set is not a function.`

Here is the code about how I define app and messageBox:

```
app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        messageBox: [{
            id: 1,
            message: 'first'
        }, {
            id: 2,
            message: 'second'
        }]
    }
});
```

and in another js file, I try to modify the data in messageBox:

```
function test() {
    app.messageBox.$set(0, {message: 'aaa'});
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The correct syntax is [`Vue.set(target, index, value)`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set).
When used inside component code or [single-file-components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html), you could use the equivalent alias: [`this.$set(target, index, value)`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set):

```
Vue.set(app.messageBox, 0, { message: 'outside component' });

// or when you don't access to `Vue`:
app.$set(app.messageBox, 0, { message: 'outside component' });

// or when `this` is the Vue instance:
this.$set(this.messageBox, 0, { message: 'inside component' })
```

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      messageBox: [{
        id: 1,
        message: 'first'
      }, {
        id: 2,
        message: 'second'
      }]
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.$set(this.messageBox, 0, { message: 'inside component' })
    }, 1000)
  }
});

setTimeout(() => {
  Vue.set(app.messageBox, 0, { message: 'outside component' });
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p v-for="msgBox of messageBox">{{msgBox.message}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This example is for update the qty of product in the array car:

```
 const indice = this.car.findIndex((pr) => pr.id === product.id);
                    if(indice===-1){
                        product.qty = 1
                        this.car.push(product)
                    }else{
                        //Vue no detectara cambios en el array si se actualiza por indice https://stackoverflow.com/a/59289650/16988223
                        //this.car[indice].qty++
                        const productUpdated = product 
                        productUpdated.qty++
                        this.$set(this.car, indice, productUpdated)
                    }
```