# v-model not update after settimeout finish Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an input in `v-for`

```
   <input
   type="number"
   min="0"
   step=".5"
   maxlength="1"
   v-model="raforditashour[index]"
   :disabled="fixraforditas[index]"
   @change="ensureRoundHours($event.target.value,index)"
   name="workvalueInHours"
   class="form-control text-right"
   id="workvalueInHours"
   @focus="$event.target.select()"
   @keydown.enter.prevent="save">
```

I want to modify 'raforditashour[index]' with a change event.

```
   ensureRoundHours(value, i) {
   setTimeout(()=>{if (value < 0.5)
 value = 0.5;
   this.raforditashour[i] = value;
   },2000)      
   },
```

But `v-model` can't recognize it and it isn't updating the input field value.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection You can read more about that, and here is the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42807888/vuejs-and-vue-set-update-array

Comment: Ty i solve it :D modify my array with this.$set(this.raforditashour,i,value)