# vue v-if can't access booleans in arrays

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vue-component, vue-reactivity

I created a vue component with the following data:

```
data: function () {
    return {
        hwshow: [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false],
    };
},
```

And a method to switch these values:

```
methods: {
    fliphw: function (index) {
        this.hwshow[index] = !this.hwshow[index];
        console.log(this.hwshow);
    },
},
```

in the html I have

```
<li v-show="hwshow[0]">foo bar</li>
```

I know the fliphw function is being called (because of the console.log), but when the value of `hwshow[0]` is true foo bar still isn't appearing. When I switch to using a boolean, instead of an array of boolean it works. Why? If I can't access an array of booleans what other solutions to the problem might there be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vuejs and Vue.set(), update array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42807888/vuejs-and-vue-set-update-array)

Answer (score 8):

[Why isn't the DOM updating?](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/#Why-isn%E2%80%99t-the-DOM-updating), this is a common gotcha:

> When you modify an Array by directly setting an index (e.g. arr[0] =
> val) or modifying its length property. Similarly, Vue.js cannot pickup
> these changes. Always modify arrays by using an Array instance method,
> or replacing it entirely.

To overcome this limitation triggering state updates in the reactivity system you can use [`Vue.set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
    data: function () {
      return {
        hwshow: [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false],
      };
    },
    methods: {
      fliphw: function (index) {
        this.$set(this.hwshow, index, !this.hwshow[index])
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <span @click="fliphw(0)">click to flip</span>
  
  <div>
   {{ hwshow }}
  </div>
  
  <ul>
     <li v-show="hwshow[0]">foo bar</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```