# How to bind class to a method that needs to change in Vue.js (v1)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frameworks

I'm completely new to Vue.js, and although I get the basics, I'm struggling with the following:

I think I need to bind a class to a method, rather than an object. I know how to do this, but this seems to run only once. I believe this is because the method technically never changes, only the objects which the method evaluates.

The scenario I have is: I have a calendar where a user needs to set a start and end date. There needs to be 'start-date' class, an 'inbetween-date' class and an 'end-date' class. This will be based on the 'nth-child' or index of the element.

How can I bind to a method that doesn't just run once? Is there any way I can force Vue to think that the method has been updated on every click?

The logic in my code is:

```
checkSelection(n) {
    var classesToReturn = [];
    if(n == this.startDate) {
       classesToReturn.push('start-date');
    }

    //Other evaluations here etc..

    return classesToReturn.join(' ');
}
```

I'm using Vue v1 as this is an existing project and don't feel comfortable enough to upgrade it to v2.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
this.$forceUpdate();
```

on the end of the function in order to update the vue.

In your case:

```
checkSelection(n) {
var classesToReturn = [];
if(n == this.startDate) {
   classesToReturn.push('start-date');
}

//Other evaluations here etc..

this.$forceUpdate();

return classesToReturn.join(' ');
}
```

**Edit**

Whenever you change some object in vue's `data` it will not automatically update, so what you should do is to call this function I've mentioned. I don't know if it should be placed in that method, but you should place it right after the line where changes to your object are made.

Comment: It looks like $forceUpdate() is only available in v2. I need a solution for v1.

Comment: Try `vue.set()` then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42807888/vuejs-and-vue-set-update-array