# How can I modify a value in a array with a click method ? [VueJS]

Tags: vue.js

I just started vuejs today. I got vue "example1" which contain as data, a variable "items". This variable contains an array "deck". This array contains multiple character stats (team, weapon, position...).

I don't know how to figure this out, if you have any solution or any direction where I can find my anwser.

I want on click on the character, to modify the gridColumn position, which is binded by "x". They are displayed on a 9*12 grid.

Thanks a lot.

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
#board {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 80px);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(9, 80px);
    grid-gap: 10px;
}
#board .card {
    background-color: pink;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<section id="board">
        <div class="card" v-for="item in items" v-bind:style="{backgroundColor:item.bg,gridColumn:item.x,gridRow:item.y}" v-on:click="move">
            {{ item.clan }}
            <br>
            {{ item.arme }}
            <br>
            {{ item.force }}
        </div>
    </section>
   <script>
        var deck = [
                    //natif
                    {
                        clan: 'natif',
                        arme:'filet',
                        force: 1,
                        bg: 'green',
                        x: 2,
                        y: 6
                    },
                    {
                        clan: 'natif',
                        arme:'filet',
                        force: 2,
                        bg: 'green',
                        x: 3,
                        y: 6
                    }
                    //etc
                ];
        var example1 = new Vue({
            el: '#board',
            data: {
                items: deck
            },
            methods: {
                move: function () {
                    // increase "x" value of the clicked item.
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the index of the item clicked and modify it inside the function by referencing the index.

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
#board {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 80px);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(9, 80px);
    grid-gap: 10px;
}
#board .card {
    background-color: pink;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<section id="board">
         <div class="card" v-for="(item,index) in items" v-bind:style="{backgroundColor:item.bg,gridColumn:item.x,gridRow:item.y}" v-on:click="move(index)">
          {{ item.clan }}
            <br>
            {{ item.arme }}
            <br>
            {{ item.force }}
        </div>
    </section>
   <script>
        var deck = [
                    //natif
                    {
                        clan: 'natif',
                        arme:'filet',
                        force: 1,
                        bg: 'green',
                        x: 2,
                        y: 6
                    },
                    {
                        clan: 'natif',
                        arme:'filet',
                        force: 2,
                        bg: 'green',
                        x: 3,
                        y: 6
                    }
                    //etc
                ];
        var example1 = new Vue({
            el: '#board',
            data: {
                items: deck
            },
            methods: {
            move: function (i) {
                this.items = this.items.map((item,indx) => {
                  if(indx === i)
                      return ({...item,x: item.x + 1});
                  return item;
                }) //modify logic accordingly
            
        }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Done. I couldn't earlier cause of the timer.

Comment: This is not how we do it in Vue, you are mutating the array in a WRONG WAY!

Comment: @saibbyweb do you have a better option ?

Comment: Yup! Wait, let me post it.

Comment: @saibbyweb actually, mutating props is considered an antipattern, but you can mutate the data since the Object accessors have all been overridden by VUE. So, it may not be the best way but it is NOT A WRONG WAY either

Comment: I have updated the code to an immutable version in either case

Comment: @HugoNicaise, the only change is we are updating the entire array and creating a new reference in the above code whereas in the previous case we overwrote the value in-place.

Comment: Thanks to both of you ! But with the following code nothing is moving anymore. Is it because of the "..." ? Or i missed something.

Comment: @HugoNicaise try the runnable version. I had a typo.

Comment: Just go through this once : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45336400/3565182

Answer (score -1):

This is how you do it according to the [OFFICIAL VUE.JS DOCUMENTATION](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats)

[Mutating the array with `Vue.set` method]:

```js
var deck = [
  //natif
  {
    clan: 'natif',
    arme: 'filet',
    force: 1,
    bg: 'green',
    x: 2,
    y: 6
  },
  {
    clan: 'natif',
    arme: 'filet',
    force: 2,
    bg: 'green',
    x: 3,
    y: 6
  }
  //etc
];
var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#board',
  data: {
    items: deck
  },
  methods: {
    move: function(index) {

      /* creating a REFERENCE of the clicked item's object */
      let modifiedObject = this.items[index];

      /*  increaseing "x" value of temporary REFERENCE */
      modifiedObject.x++;

      /* Mutating the items array WITHOUT LOSING    REACTIVITY by replacing the existing object with local modified object */
      Vue.set(this.items, index, modifiedObject);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#board {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 40px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(9, 40px);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

#board .card {
  background-color: pink;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<section id="board">
  <div class="card" v-for="(item,index) in items" v-bind:style="{backgroundColor:item.bg,gridColumn:item.x,gridRow:item.y}" v-on:click="move(index)">
    {{ item.clan }}
    <br> {{ item.arme }}
    <br> {{ item.force }}
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: `/* creating a copy of the clicked item's object */
      let modifiedObject = this.items[index];`  does not create a copy since this.items[index] is an object and only a reference is passed

Comment: my bad, just to keep it simple for the newbie.

Comment: well, in effect, it would also equate to the "wrong" way of doing things, since you are mutating.  `Vue.set(` is used when new keys are added. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: my only aim was to keep it reactive. your initial answer totally defeated the purpose of using vue, that's why I pointed it out.