# How does vuejs react to component data updated asynchronously

Tags: vuejs2

I am very new with vuejs and recently started to try to replace some old jquery code that I have and make it reactive with vuejs. The thing is I have a component that gets information from a nodejs server via socket.io asynchronously.

When I get the data and update my component's data I see the changes when I console log it but it does not change the DOM the way I want it to do.

What is the proper way to grab data asynchronously and use it inside a component? I post some parts of my code so you can see it. I will appreciate any advice you can give me. Thanks in advance!

```
Vue.component('chat', {
      data() {
        return {
          chat: null,
          commands: [],
          chatOpened: false,
        }
      },

      props: [
        'io',
        'messages',
        'channels',
        'connectChat',
        'roomChat',
        'user',
        'userId',
        'soundRoute',
      ],

      methods: {
        openChat() {
          this.chatOpened = true;
        },

        closeChat() {
          this.chatOpened = false;
        },
      },

      created() {
        this.chat = this.$io.connect(this.connectChat);
        this.commands.push('clear');

        let self = this;

        $.each(this.channels, function(index, value) {
          self.chat.emit('join', {room: index, user: self.user, userId: self.userId}, function(err, cb) {
            if (!err) {
              users = cb.users;
              messages = cb.messages;

              if (messages.length > 0) {
                self.channels[index].loaded = true;
              }

              //some more code
            }
          });
        });

        console.log(this.channels);
      },

      template: `
          <div>
            <div id="container-chat-open-button" @click="openChat" :class="{hide : chatOpened}">
              <div>+90</div>
              <i class="fas fa-comment-alt"></i>
            </div>
            <div id="container-chat" class="chat__container" :class="{open : chatOpened}">
              <div id="container-chat-close-button" @click="closeChat">
                <span>
                  <div>
                    <i class="fas fa-comment-alt"></i>
                    @{{ messages.chat_lobby_icon_title }}
                  </div>
                  <i class="icon-arrowdown"></i>
                </span>
              </div>
              <div id="alert-chat" class="chat__container-notifications animated flash"></div>
              <div class="row">
                <ul>
                  <li v-for="channel in channels" v-show="channel.loaded === true">Channel loaded</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        `
      });
```

I would expect to see the list of channels with messsages but instead I don't see the list even thought I see my channels with the loaded attribute set to true (by default they all have this attribute set to false).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vuejs and Vue.set(), update array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42807888/vuejs-and-vue-set-update-array)

Comment: Please check the related post and make sure to not manipulate array indexes in data() like you do.

Comment: @Borjante thanks for your answer. I read the post you mentioned but using Vue.set is not working for me. Could you please let me know how I should proceed to change my self.channels in order to add one attribute to one specific channel? Thanks again!

Comment: One issue i do notice is you shouldn't be updating props directly. The Vue pattern for updates is parent -> child. If child needs to update data, it should emit changes and the parent should react.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it's this part that is not working as expected.

```
if (messages.length > 0) {
   self.channels[index].loaded = true;
}
```

The reactive way of doing this is by setting the full object again.

```
Vue.set(self.channels, index, {
   ...self.channels[index],
   loaded: true
}
```

EDIT 1:

```
this.channels.forEach((channel) => {
    this.chat.emit('join', {room: index, user: self.user, userId: self.userId}, (err, cb) => {
        if (!err) {
            users = cb.users;
            messages = cb.messages;

            if (messages.length > 0) {
                Vue.set(self.channels, index, {
                    ...self.channels[index],
                    loaded: true
                }
            }

            //some more code
        }
    });
})
```

You'll need to add support for the rest-spread-operator using babel.

Comment: I tried it but still not working. I see the changes when I log the self.channels variable but those changes are not reflected on the DOM...

Comment: Then you are out of the scope, I'm going to replace that strange _self and jQuery