# Computed property returning state variable isn't reactive

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-reactivity

For a hangman game I have a `Word.vue` component in which I'm trying to initialise an array named `wordToGuessAsArray` containing *n* empty items (*n* = number of letters in word to guess):

```
<template>
  <section>
    <div v-for="(letter, i) in wordToGuessAsArray" :key="i">
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    wordToGuessAsArray () {
      return this.$store.state.wordToGuessAsArray
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    const wordToGuess = 'strawberry'
    for (var i = 0; i < wordToGuess.length; i++) {
      this.$store.commit('SET_WORD_AS_ARRAY_PUSH')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Below is the content of my `store` relevant to this question:

```
state: {
  wordToGuessAsArray: [],
},
mutations: {
  SET_WORD_AS_ARRAY_PUSH (state) {
    state.wordToGuessAsArray.push('')
  },
  SET_WORD_AS_ARRAY (state, value) {
    state.wordToGuessAsArray[value.i] = value.letter
  }
}
```

My problem is the following. In my `Keyboard.vue` component, when user picks a letter that does indeed belong to the word to guess, I update my state thus:

```
this.$store.commit('SET_WORD_AS_ARRAY', { letter, i })
```

I expect this mutation to update the word in my `Word.vue` component here:

```
<div v-for="(letter, i) in wordToGuessAsArray" :key="i">
```

Yet it doesn't. `wordToGuessAsArray` seems non reactive, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `state.wordToGuessAsArray[value.i] = value.letter` is not reactive.
Because Vue.js only watch array methods like `push` or `splice`.

You need to do `this.$set(state.wordToGuessAsArray, value.i, value.letter);`

Or in Vuex :
`Vue.set(state.wordToGuessAsArray, value.i, value.letter);` and import Vue in your file.

Read more here :

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

[Vuejs and Vue.set(), update array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42807888/vuejs-and-vue-set-update-array)

Comment: Thanks, but can I do this in the store? I'm getting `this.$set is not a function` error