# VueJs - Updating class with a setInterval function not working

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I want to make paragraph elements appear every 1s by switching their classes from a class with opacity 0 to a class with opacity 1.
To achieve this I am using a mounted() function that runs a setInterval function that updates the array damm that switches the classes of the paragraph elements.
So far I managed to change the array but not the classes.

HTML

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template>
  <div>
<section class=fuckingimage>
    <p :class="{content: this.damm[0], contentout: !this.damm[0]}">{{txt[0]}}</p>
    <p :class="{content: this.damm[1], contentout: !this.damm[1]}">{{txt[1]}}</p>
    <p :class="{content: this.damm[2], contentout: !this.damm[2]}">{{txt[2]}}</p>
    <p :class="{content: this.damm[3], contentout: !this.damm[3]}">{{txt[3]}}</p>
    <p :class="{content: this.damm[4], contentout: !this.damm[4]}">{{txt[4]}}</p>
    <p :class="{content: this.damm[6], contentout: !this.damm[5]}">{{txt[5]}}</p>
    
    <h3 @click="show">..So contact me!</h3>
    <div v-show="this.var" >
    <h2>ig: brunosousareneg</h2>
    <span></span>
    </div>
</section>
  </div>
</template>
```

VueJs

```js
<script>
export default {
 
  data() {
        return {
      var: false,
      damm: [false, false, false, false, false, false],
      zero: [false, false, false, false, false, false],
      txt: ['aaaaa','eeeee','iiiii','ooooo','uuuuu','fffff'],
      i: 0,
      y: ''
        }
  },
  methods: {
      show(){
          this.var = true;
      },
      para(){
        this.damm[this.i] = true
        this.test = true;
        this.i++
        if(this.i === 6){
          clearInterval(this.y);
        }
        console.log('runnin ' + this.damm)
      }
  },
  mounted(){ 
     this.y = setInterval(this.para, 1000)}
    }
    
  

</script>
```

CSS

```css
<style scoped lang="stylus">
.fuckingimage
  font-size 24px
  color yellow
  text-align center
  text-justify newspaper
  overflow hidden
  position relative
  transition all 1s ease
  background-image url('../assets/fc3.png')
  background-position center
  background-size 100%
  height 800px

h3 
  border solid 3px gold
  width 300px
  margin 0 auto
  border-radius 10px


h3:hover { cursor: pointer;
            color: gold; 
            transform: scale(1.15);
            transition: all 1s ease}

span {
        width:50%;
        background: yellow;
        display:block;
        height: 5px;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

h2 
  color blue

.content
  font-size 24px
  color yellow
  text-align center
  text-justify newspaper
  transition all 1s ease 
  opacity 1

.contentout
  transform translate(-10%) 
  opacity 0
  font-size 24px
  color yellow
  
</style>
```

What is strange is that even though the array damm is changing from false to true the paragraph element class is not changing, but when I press the h2, it does what is intended thanks to the v-show, but also changes the class of the paragraph elements which were supposed to have changed automatically.

Comment: This bug is due to the fact that you are manipulating the array outside of the Vue watcher scope. Check out  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42808068/4515720) which describes how to manipulate the array using Vue.js methods.

Comment: So I did this change and it changed nothing  mounted(){ 
     this.y = setInterval(function(){
       this.damm[this.i] = true
        this.test = true;
        this.i++
        if(this.i === 6){
          clearInterval(this.y);
     }}.bind(this), 1000)}
    }

Comment: as I said before the app is changing the array but the array isn't changing the class so the problem isn't from the array, but from the array not being updating the classes

Comment: I understand your issue. You cannot manipulate the array like that and maintain the binding in Vue. Vue will not pickup the changes to change the class when you directly modify an element of the array.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. So how can I change the classes automatically every second on component load? I tryed the bind(this) method as I wrote before and it didn't work

Comment: Please look at the answer that I linked. There is a link on that answer that talks about the methods you need to use to manipulate the array and have Vue pickup the changes

Comment: ahah Sr Evan thank you so much. I solved by instead of changing from false to true I used the push() method to an empty array. Thank you so much!

Comment: :) No problem! Glad that it solved your issue!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vuejs and Vue.set(), update array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42807888/vuejs-and-vue-set-update-array)

Comment: Yes it did, once again thank you Mr Evan