# How can I update changing content automatically in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, data-binding

I am creating a sorting algorithms visualizer. I have written the following code...

```
    <v-select
      label="Choose Algorithm"
      append-icon="mdi-chart-bar"
      :items="sortingAlgorithmOptions"
      v-model="sortingAlgorithmChoice"
      color="secondary darken-4"
    ></v-select>

    <v-btn class="secondary darken-3 mt-3" @click="callSortingAlgorithmFunction">
      <span>Start sorting</span>
      <v-icon right>mdi-shuffle</v-icon>
    </v-btn>

    <v-card
      flat
      class="red d-inline-block mr-2"
      width="20px"
      v-for="item in arrayToSort"
      :key="item.id"
      :height="item * 10"
      ref="arrayToSort"
    ></v-card>

    data: () => ({
        sortingAlgorithmOptions: ["Merge Sort", "Quick Sort", "Bubble Sort"],
        sortingAlgorithmChoice: "Sorting",
        arrayToSort: []
      }),

    methods: {
      bubbleSort: function() {
        // Not yet implemented
        let n = this.arrayToSort.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
          for (let j = i + 1; j < n - i; ++j) {
            if (this.arrayToSort[j] < this.arrayToSort[j - 1]) {
              let temp = this.arrayToSort[j - 1];
              this.arrayToSort[j - 1] = this.arrayToSort[j];
              this.arrayToSort[j] = temp;
            }
          }
        }
      },
      callSortingAlgorithmFunction: function() {
        let event = this.sortingAlgorithmChoice;
        console.log(this.sortingAlgorithmChoice)
        if (event == "Merge Sort") {
          this.mergeSort();
        } else if (event == "Quick Sort") {
          this.quickSort();
        } else if (event == "Bubble Sort") {
          this.bubbleSort();
        }
      },

      // Called on created
      intializeRandomArray: function() {
        this.arrayToSort = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < 52; ++i) {
          this.arrayToSort.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 55) + 10);
        }
      }
    }
```

But this code doesn't seem to be sorting when I click the *Start sorting* button.

However, if I change the selected option to some other sorting algorithm, the canvas updates with the new orientation of bars. I have put in lots of hours, gone through many revert backs and searched their docs, forums, etc., but I can not figure out what's wrong here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue cannot detect when you directly set an item in an array with the index like this:

`this.arrayToSort[j] = temp`

To overcome this you need to do this:

`this.$set(this.arrayToSort, j, temp)`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42808068/5671919

Read more here : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays