# VueJs Not Updating Array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to make a dynamic menu at vue, but, while I trying to apply a "active" css class to the menu item, not work, I see the menu variable "menuFomartado" is not updating by VUE, what I thinking wrong?

This code only works while loading page again..

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      menuFomartado: [],
      menu: [
        {
          icon: "fa fa-chart-area",
          pageName: "dashboard",
          title: "Dashboard",
          role: "admin"
        },
        {
          icon: "fa fa-user-circle",
          pageName: "clientes",
          title: "Clientes",
          role: "admin"
        },
    
      ]
    };
  },
  computed: {
    sideMenu() {
      return this.nestedMenu(this.menu);
    }
  },
  watch: {
    $route() {
      this.menuFomartado = this.sideMenu;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.menuFomartado = this.nestedMenu(this.sideMenu);
  },
  methods: {
    nestedMenu(menu) {
      menu.forEach((item, key) => {
        if (typeof item !== "string" && item.pageName != "") {
          menu[key].active = item.pageName == this.$route.name;
        }
      });

      return menu;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42807888/vuejs-and-vue-set-update-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based in @pierre-said from post [Vuejs and Vue.set(), update array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42807888/vuejs-and-vue-set-update-array)

I just changed the line

```
menu[key].active = item.pageName == this.$route.name;
```

To

```
this.$set(menu[key], "active", item.pageName == this.$route.name);
```

And works fine