# Vuejs and Vuex not rendering updated array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to update the quantity property in a Vuex array called "cartItems", however it doesn't update it with the v-for loop.

ShoppingCart.vue (Parent)

```
<div class="cart_row_container">
 <CartItem v-for="(item, index) in $store.getters.getCart"
  :item="item"
  :loopIndex="index"
  :key="item.id"
 />
</div>
```

CartItem.vue (child)

```
<div class="item_row">
 <h4 class="quantity_text">{{item.quantity}}</h4>
</div>
```

Imported props:
    props: ['item', 'loopIndex']

Vuex:

```
state:{
    cartItems: []
},
mutations:{
 changeQuantity(state, data){ 
        let newQuantity = state.cartItems[data.index]
        newQuantity.quantity += data.value
        this._vm.$set(state.cartItems, data.index, newQuantity)
    }
},

getters:{
    getCartLenght: state => {
        return state.cartItems.length
    },
    getCart: state => {
        return state.cartItems
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hello Alexander, and welcome to SO. Try moving the invocation of $store.getters.getCart to a computed function in the parent component.

Comment: Thanks @andrewhl! Yep tried that just now, no change, still not updating :(

Comment: do you have some warnings or errors in browser console

Comment: Nope, no errors or warnings @BoussadjraBrahim

Comment: @AlexanderDahlberg i tried out your example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/6lwj4mwnxr) and it works, you could add additional code and fork it and give me the link

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Yes indeed it workes with your example, I managed to figure out that it does update the DOM on the items that are already in the cartItem array, however if I push a item into it and try to increment that object that does not update the DOM.

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim The strange part is that it does work when you do it via the Codesandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/wy65yv8z08

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Never mind I posted a quick answer down below, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so for some reason when ever you have an object and want to add a key to it and the object has already been made Vue and Vuex won't recognize that key of the object as reactive, so even though you are updating the value it won't re-render the DOM.

How I solved it, simply added the Quantity attribute to my database table and set it by default to 1.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Vue.set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) to set a new object property. This method ensures the property is created as a reactive property.

> **Usage**:
>
> Adds a property to a reactive object, ensuring the new property is
> also reactive, so triggers view updates. This must be used to add new
> properties to reactive objects, as Vue cannot detect normal property
> additions (e.g. this.myObject.newProperty = 'hi').

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36671106/what-is-the-difference-between-vm-set-and-vue-set